# Pararells + Mac OS + Visual Studio 2013

Tags: macos, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, virtualization

I Have i Macbook pro 13" with OS X Yoshemite.

I will take a course in ASP.net MVC 4.

I Know that i can use Parrarels and run Windows 8 virtually BUT will this solution work with the Visual Studio 2013 build in localhost without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as I do this all the time and have used Parallels Desktop on Mac OSX holding IIS and Visual Studio since 2008.